# How to use Maven to build a war and use Jenkins to deploy to Tomcat server

Tags: java, maven

I hava create a servlet project. The project structure is like that:

```
.
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- web
 |   |-- css
 |   |-- fonts
 |   |-- image
 |   |-- js
 |   |-- css
 |   |-- WEB-INF
 |   |   `-- web.xml
 |   `-- index.jsp
 `-- src
     `-- MyServlet.java
```

And my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <finalName>web-app-name</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to run `mvn war:war`, I found it create a new example.war under target folder. However, the example.war is **empty**.

What I want to do is to create a *.war and deploy this *.war to Tomcat by using Jenkins. Anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're following the correct project structure. It looks like you need:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- webapp
            |-- WEB-INF
            |   `-- web.xml
            `-- index.jsp
        `-- java
```

See the [Maven Archetype for War files](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I MUST follow this structure? Actually I generated above structure by IDEA automatically..

Comment: Maven is convention over configuration. The best way to make things work well is to follow the convention. That's where maven archetypes help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Ashley's advice.

Furthermore, build your project with `mvn clean verify`. Running the war plugin separately does not work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to re-structure my folder like Ashley's advice. but I use 'mvn clean verify' and still generated an empty war file. So I use 'mvn war:war'.. Now I can see the js,css file inside. but still cannot see my *.class file in it